# Responsive Layout problem with layout when shrinking, media query and grid

Tags: html, css, gridview, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to make the columns to go from 2 to 1 inside of the content of the page when I'm shrinking it to tablet or phone size with media query.

The aside is suppose to go down under the content when the website is shrinking so everything will fall under each object. At the moment nothing is happening with the media query and everything is just going into each other when I try to shrink the website.

I have tried using [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp) to get more information from, but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
*{ box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; 
}

body {
    height: 70%;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background: #CCFFFF;

}

img.align-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2em;}

img.medium {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;}

img.small {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;}

a:link {
  background-color: #6699cc;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.1em 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:visited {
    color: #0B6623;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: #01579B;
}

a{
    cursor: pointer; 
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed; 
    width: auto;
}


#page {
    min-height: 70%;
    min-width: 90%;
    margin: 1em auto 1em auto;
    z-index: auto;
    background: #CCCCFF;
}

header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0.1em;
    height: 20%;
    padding: 2em;
    border: 0.25em;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width: thick; 
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #CAE9F5;
    margin: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    min-width: 95%;
    max-width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

nav {
    height: 2em;
    z-index: auto;
    display: inline;
}

#content { 
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    z-index: auto; 
    width: 60%;
    max-height: 40%;
    max-width: 65%; 
    min-height: 40%;
    min-width: 65%; 
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 25%;
    background-color: green;
}

aside {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    z-index: auto; 
    max-height: 50%;
    max-width: 30%;
    min-height: 50%;
    min-width: 30%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.2em;
    bottom: 1em;
    clear: both;
    z-index: auto;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 95%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    .content { 
        column-count: 1;
        column-width: 100%; }

    [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px max-width: 767px) {
  /* For tablets: */
    .content{
    column-count: 1;
    column-width: 100%;
  }

  .col-1 {width: 30%;}
  .col-2 {width: 60%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 30%;}
  .col-9 {width: 100%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}

}
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="page">
            <header>
            <h1>This</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">Index</a>
                <a href="home.html">Home</a>
                <a href="this.html">This</a>
                <a href="then.html">Then</a>
                <a href="what.html">What</a>
            </nav>
            </header>

            <div class="col-2">
            <div id="content">
            <figure><img src="images/window.gif" class="align-left medium" alt="New photo"><figcaption>  This is a photo  </figcaption></figure>
                <article><br />
                <h2>Heading 2 </h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pharetra risus quam, et lacinia ante malesuada eget. 
                Morbi erat mauris, rutrum eget tortor vitae, venenatis volutpat odio. Maecenas feugiat mollis est quis sagittis. 
                Etiam vitae lorem ac purus efficitur scelerisque. Integer venenatis magna ante, laoreet efficitur tortor consequat a. 
                Sed a est scelerisque, auctor risus id, tempus nisi. Donec fermentum laoreet ullamcorper. Curabitur pulvinar massa et nisl hendrerit, ut lobortis urna hendrerit.</p>
                <br />
                <p>Vestibulum ac blandit nisl. Curabitur dapibus sem efficitur, molestie sem in, scelerisque velit. Cras quis ex lacinia massa egestas pulvinar in tristique nulla. 
                Vestibulum aliquam a leo sed mollis. Nullam quis dapibus purus. Cras dui urna, cursus eget enim et, dignissim tincidunt turpis. 
                Praesent lacinia, purus eget volutpat euismod, nibh arcu convallis velit, vitae eleifend ligula justo sagittis augue. 
                Duis lobortis nulla in sapien vestibulum, et cursus enim scelerisque. Duis a erat non leo mattis pulvinar finibus at augue.</p>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </article>

                <article>
                <h4>Heading 2 </h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pharetra risus quam, et lacinia ante malesuada eget. 
                Morbi erat mauris, rutrum eget tortor vitae, venenatis volutpat odio. Maecenas feugiat mollis est quis sagittis. 
                Etiam vitae lorem ac purus efficitur scelerisque. Integer venenatis magna ante, laoreet efficitur tortor consequat a. 
                Sed a est scelerisque, auctor risus id, tempus nisi. Donec fermentum laoreet ullamcorper. Curabitur pulvinar massa et nisl hendrerit, ut lobortis urna hendrerit.</p>
                <br />
                <p>Vestibulum ac blandit nisl. Curabitur dapibus sem efficitur, molestie sem in, scelerisque velit. Cras quis ex lacinia massa egestas pulvinar in tristique nulla. 
                Vestibulum aliquam a leo sed mollis. Nullam quis dapibus purus. Cras dui urna, cursus eget enim et, dignissim tincidunt turpis. 
                Praesent lacinia, purus eget volutpat euismod, nibh arcu convallis velit, vitae eleifend ligula justo sagittis augue. 
                Duis lobortis nulla in sapien vestibulum, et cursus enim scelerisque. Duis a erat non leo mattis pulvinar finibus at augue.</p>>Project work with software engineering, 15hp</li>
                </ul>
                </article>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-8">
        <aside>
        <h4>Heading 2 </h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pharetra risus quam, et lacinia ante malesuada eget. 
                Morbi erat mauris, rutrum eget tortor vitae, venenatis volutpat odio. Maecenas feugiat mollis est quis sagittis. 
                Etiam vitae lorem ac purus efficitur scelerisque. Integer venenatis magna ante, laoreet efficitur tortor consequat a. 
                Sed a est scelerisque, auctor risus id, tempus nisi. Donec fermentum laoreet ullamcorper. Curabitur pulvinar massa et nisl hendrerit, ut lobortis urna hendrerit.</p>
                <br />
                <p>Vestibulum ac blandit nisl. Curabitur dapibus sem efficitur, molestie sem in, scelerisque velit. Cras quis ex lacinia massa egestas pulvinar in tristique nulla. 
                Vestibulum aliquam a leo sed mollis. Nullam quis dapibus purus. Cras dui urna, cursus eget enim et, dignissim tincidunt turpis. 
                Praesent lacinia, purus eget volutpat euismod, nibh arcu convallis velit, vitae eleifend ligula justo sagittis augue. 
                Duis lobortis nulla in sapien vestibulum, et cursus enim scelerisque. Duis a erat non leo mattis pulvinar finibus at augue.</p>>Project work with software engineering, 15hp</li>
                </ul>
        </aside>
        </div>

        <footer>
        <br />
            <details>
                <summary>Copyright 2019</summary>
                <p> By a person </p>
                <p> Doink!</p>
            </details>
        </footer>

        </div>
    </body>
```

This is how it looks as a picture: 
[image: https://imgshare.io/image/WScnw]
[image]

Comment: Just going off a quick look; you're using the class selector `.content` instead of the id selector `#content` in your media queries

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I managed to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Matt.Hamer5 says the main problem is that you are using .content rather than #content.

But then you will also hit a problem that the content has fixed min and max widths, you'll need to change these.

Something like this in the media query:

```
#content { 
    column-count: 1;
    column-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
aside {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```